# Generalization of QR factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, gram-schmidt

Find the QR factorization of the general $2 \times 2$ matrix $A =  \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Not sure what you expect. A QR factorization always exists.

Comment: A=QR. How can I express QR in terms of a,b,c,d?

Comment: @MartinArgerami edited the question

Answer (score 2):

It would have probably been easier to ask [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=QR+decomposition+%7B%7Ba,b%7D,%7Bc,d%7D%7D) than Math.SE. You have $A=QR$, where 
$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\bar a}{\sqrt{|a|^2+|b|^2}}&\dfrac{\bar c}{\sqrt{|a|^2+|b|^2}}\\
\frac{\bar b|c|^2-c\bar a\bar d}{\sqrt{(|a|^2+|c|^2)(|b|^2|c|^2+|a|^2|d|^2-2\text{Re}\,ad\bar b\bar c)}}
&\dfrac{\bar d|a|^2-a\bar b\bar c}{\sqrt{(|a|^2+|c|^2)(|b|^2|c|^2+|a|^2|d|^2-2\text{Re}\,ad\bar b\bar c)}}
\end{bmatrix},
$$

$$
R=\begin{bmatrix}
 {\sqrt{|a|^2+|b|^2}}&\dfrac{b\bar a-d\bar c}{\sqrt{|a|^2+|b|^2}}\\
0&\dfrac{\bar d|a|^2-a\bar b\bar c}{\sqrt{\frac{|b|^2|c|^2+|a|^2|d|^2-2\text{Re}\,ad\bar b\bar c}{|a|^2+|c|^2}}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you Martin, however I'm looking for the steps not just the final result.

Comment: @user1023 The steps are just Gram-Schmidt, being careful about the singular case.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51MRHjKSbtk This link was super helpful for anyone looking for the answer